# Indent each line more than the previous line in a single paragraph div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress theme and trying to get a single div class paragraph to look like this:

[image]

I have seen the following which is great, but don't want to be in italics:

[Is there a simple way to dynamically indent each line in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509655/is-there-a-simple-way-to-dynamically-indent-each-line-in-a-div)

I've tried doing a `transform: skewX(5deg);` on the container and then `transform: skewX(-5deg);` on the text class but it goes back to normal text.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at CSS Shapes, for example: http://alistapart.com/article/css-shapes-101

Comment: Took a few attempts but got this working nicely, thanks!